# Weird runtime error with iOS 8 and XCode 6 beta 4

Tags: xcode, ios8, runtimeexception

We have a UITableView object in our storyboard that is assigned to a custom class. When I load the view and try to select a row, the application crashes. I've been putting breakpoints up and down my class—the most intuitive one being at didSelectRowAtIndexPath—but all of this is to no avail. App just crashes before I get to any of my breakpoints.

This bug only exists in iOS8. Runs fine in iOS7. Any ideas what is causing this? Below is a log of my console.

```
CoreData: warning: Property 'year' is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'Term' that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalar type.  Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended.
2014-08-04 13:45:47.415 Grades[29475:2823481] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7fb9728ba400> should have parent view controller:<SyllabusDetailViewController: 0x7fb9706a96a0> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7fb97086fa00>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108fcfc35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001088c2a1c objc_exception_throw + 45
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108fcfb6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
  3   UIKit                               0x00000001070b348d -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 184
  4   UIKit                               0x000000010764a4a2 -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 435
  5   UIKit                               0x000000010764b07a __43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke + 85
  6   UIKit                               0x0000000106ffdb9e +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
  7   UIKit                               0x000000010764ae4b -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 288
  8   UIKit                               0x0000000107646e3b -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
  9   UIKit                               0x000000010744214e -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1054
  10  UIKit                               0x00000001070ff32d -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 468
  11  UIKit                               0x0000000106ff9453 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 99
  12  UIKit                               0x00000001076a4a0f -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
  13  UIKit                               0x000000010733d3d1 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 177
  14  UIKit                               0x000000010733f440 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2263
  15  UIKit                               0x0000000107334b5d _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 262
  16  UIKit                               0x0000000107333134 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1095
  17  UIKit                               0x0000000107338556 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke690 + 371
  18  UIKit                               0x0000000107338312 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 254
  19  UIKit                               0x000000010732d87b _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2858
  20  UIKit                               0x0000000106fd3b36 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
  21  UIKit                               0x0000000106fd4763 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
  22  UIKit                               0x0000000106fa1811 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
  23  UIKit                               0x0000000106fae8ae _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17707
  24  UIKit                               0x0000000106f8a009 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1967
  25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108f057f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
  26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108efb16d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
  27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108efa7a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
  28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108efa1d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
  29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b330a3a GSEventRunModal + 161
  30  UIKit                               0x0000000106f8d280 UIApplicationMain + 1282
  31  Grades                              0x0000000106300003 main + 115
  32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001095ea145 start + 1
  33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fixed the problem. Had some bad CONTRL+drag connections between my Storyboard objects and my IBOutlets. Turned those off and now the problem is gone.

Comment: I am getting a similar issue. Can you explain what kind of 'Bad ctrl+drag' connection were there?